# What does << represent in python?

Tags: python, syntax

Python says

```
1 << 16 = 65536
```

What operation does `<<` performs in Python?

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Comment: [Arithmetic shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift)

Comment: see http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html?highlight=bit%20shift#shifting-operations

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is the left shift operator for Python.
A left shift operation, as the name says, move bits to the left.

Suppose you have 2 whose binary representation is 0010.
So  `2<<2`  means to shift the bits twice to the left:

0010 -> 0100 -> 1000

1000 is the binary representation for 8. Mathematically, left shifting is the same as multiplying a number by a power of 2 :  `a<<b == a*2^b` , but as the operation is done only by shifting, it is much faster than doing multiplications.

Comment: Could you comment on whether or not it is a good idea to replace exponentiation with bit-shifts where possible?

Comment: @Genre It is a good idea. A bit shift is generally a single assembly instruction while exponentiation might take several. Good libraries and compilers may try to optimize for the case in which the base is a 2 power. A con is that code becomes less readable (1<<16 is not readable as 2^16). So you need to evaluate if the savings compensate for the loss of readability.

Answer (score 9):

This is `left shift operator`

`1<<16` implies 1 to be shifted left by 16 bits.

Answer (score 5):

`<<` it's the left-shift operator in Python. Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations) for further details.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to think about it is 1 times 2^16.

So whenever you see x << y interpret it as:

x * 2^y